# chef environmental variables in ubuntu

Tags: sinatra, chef-infra

Ok, I'm using magic_shell_environment (from magic_shell) to set an environmental

My app relies on those variables to be present to present during when starting up so it knows it's on a deployment box (rather then local).

The first time this runs however those environmentals don't exist so the app starts up in development mode, I have to manually restart the app to get it to work.

How can I make it so that the environmental variable is there so that the app can see it?

My app starts with `app install`

Comment: You may set the env variable in the execute resource you're using, or simply a `ENV['env_var']='the value'`  before the execute resource. Without any recipe code it's hard to tell the best way...

Comment: That wouldn't work, as the app it's starting won't pick up on it as it's separate ruby runtime, doing `ENV['env_var']='the value'` would only set it for the recipe and nothing else

Comment: Execute resource pass the actual Env to subprocess. But as I said, Without knowing your startup script or some code around your startup it's near impossible to help you

Comment: do you mean pass the env as an argument to the start up script?

Comment: Nope, you have two solutions, the process launched by execute will inherit the current ENV or you may add specific Env variables for the subprocess only with the environment attribute of the execute resource, see HTTP://docs.chef.io and search for execute resource for examples. I'm on phone and can't give a better link this evening

Comment: AH, you mean environment attribute of the execute resource, yes, that would work, it only needs the presence of the env, not the value. could you please post this is as an answer so I can tick it? I don't like leaving questions without an answer, I do mean when you have the time of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, writing this as an answer (never too late :) )

You have two solutions:

1. Set the env var with ruby `ENV['variable'] = "whatever"` in the recipe before the `execute` resource.The process launched will inherit the environment of the parent process, here the chef-client run environment.
2. Use the `environment` attribute of the `execute` resource ([doc](http://docs.chef.io/chef/resources.html#execute))

The environment attribute works also for other `script` resources as they inherit from `execute`.